# Qt widget background differs from Linux to Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt4, pyqt4

I'm about to implement a cross-platform Qt program. I have one problem I don't understand: when the program is executed on Windows, I get the wrong background color for some widgets. In the first place, I wrote the program in C++ with the very same results, so I think this is not a Python specific problem.

I stripped my code down to a simple program that shows the "error". I'm not sure which widget causes it, so I simply included all elements that are used in the real program.

Here's how it looks on Linux:

[image: Widget on Linux]

And here's the Windows rendering with the wrong background:

[image: Widget on Linux]

Here's the code:

```py
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QTabWidget, QWidget, \
                        QGroupBox, QVBoxLayout, QScrollArea, QFrame, QHBoxLayout, \
                        QGridLayout, QLabel

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        mainWidget = QWidget(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(mainWidget)
        self.setCentralWidget(mainWidget)
        self.tabWidget = QTabWidget(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        self.scorePage = ScorePage()
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.scorePage, 'Some Tab')
        self.scorePage.reload()

class GameWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GameWidget, self).__init__()
        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        boogerLabel = QLabel(self)
        boogerLabel.setText('Some Text')
        layout.addWidget(boogerLabel, 0, 0)

class ScorePage(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ScorePage, self).__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.scoreBox = QGroupBox(self)
        self.scoreBoxLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.scoreBox)
        layout.addWidget(self.scoreBox)
        self.scoreBoxScroll = QScrollArea(self.scoreBox)
        self.scoreBoxScroll.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.scoreBoxLayout.addWidget(self.scoreBoxScroll)
        self.scoreBoxWidget = QWidget(self)

    def reload(self):
        self.scoreBoxWidget.deleteLater()
        self.scoreBoxWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.scoreBoxWidgetLayout = QHBoxLayout(self.scoreBoxWidget)
        newGame = GameWidget()
        self.scoreBoxWidgetLayout.addWidget(newGame)
        self.scoreBoxScroll.setWidget(self.scoreBoxWidget)
        self.scoreBoxWidget.setAutoFillBackground(False)

def main(argv):
    app = QApplication(sys.argv, True)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

How can I get and set the correct backgrolund color (the one from the QGroupBox)?

Thanks in advance for all help about this!

Comment: Where is the supposed problem? The styling is different between the platforms, so that's to be expected.

Comment: The problem is that all other widgets in my program don't have a different background color but the one of the tab widget (Qlabels, QCheckBoxes etc.). It's more a cosmetic problem, but the behavior is a bit strange: when the widget is not added by calling the reload() function but by the constructor, the "right" background color is set. So I think this is due to my implementation and could be fixed somehow. I don't think that this is expected behavior. Without setting setAutoFillBackground(False) for the scoreBoxWidget, I also get the "wrong" color on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out what's causing this. It's the background of the QScrollArea (which is probably uses the same as the QTabWidget on my Linux installation, so that I didn't see it).

Simply defining the background of the QScrollArea as transparent solves it:

```py
self.scoreBoxScroll.setStyleSheet('QScrollArea { background-color: transparent; }')
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey some time ago I faced with similar problem and I fixed that by adding windows styles which are different than that default:

Here is my main for your example which works as you want:

```
def main(argv):
    app = QApplication(sys.argv, True)
    from platform import system
    if system() == "Windows":
        app.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create("windows"))
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

QStyleFactory is in QtGui so you have to extend your import

Comment: Thanks for your answer :-) After applying your proposed changes the problem is not visible anymore, but I think it just masks the problem but does not solve it … as soon as a more modern style (like 'windowsvista') is used, the problem is the same. I think the wrong background color just disappears because the 'windows' style uses less colors …

Comment: Yeah it still just workaround. From my side I can only suggest to write your own styles.

Comment: My problem is that each and every widget apart from this one is displayed correctly. So I think it's due to the implementation I made and can be fixed somehow …